Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374) pyzbar
This situation occurs when scanning a certain QR code.
Most can succeed.
how to solve it, thanks.
this is my code：
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

def decode_qr_code(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    decoded_objects = decode(image)
    if decoded_objects:
        for obj in decoded_objects:
            print('Type:', obj.type)
            print('Data:', obj.data.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        print('No QR code found in the image.')

decode_qr_code('moduCode.jpg')

python --version
Python 3.8.10

pyzbar                    0.1.9
Pillow                    10.1.0


Please include the actual QR code, or barring that, a reproducible example that's not confidential.  What kind of QR code is it?

When dealing with a corrupted QR code, it's beneficial to standardize the processing so it's not crucial to know the specifics of the corruption. In the revised code; If a process crashes due to a corrupted image, it will not affect the processing of other images.   Additionally, consider using .convert("RGB") when opening the image, as some images may be in 'BGR' format.
from multiprocessing import Process
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

def decode_qr_code(image_path):
    try:
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        decoded_objects = decode(image)
        if decoded_objects:
            for obj in decoded_objects:
                print(f'Decoding {image_path}:')
                print('Type:', obj.type)
                print('Data:', obj.data.decode('utf-8'))
        else:
            print(f'No QR code found in {image_path}.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred while decoding {image_path}: {e}')

def process_image(image_path):
    process = Process(target=decode_qr_code, args=(image_path,))
    process.start()
    process.join()  # Wait for the process to complete

# List of image paths to process
image_paths = ['qr1.jpg', 'qr2.jpg', 'qr3.jpg']

for path in image_paths:
    process_image(path)


Thank you. It was indeed a process crash
